# Renaming a $_FILES (file) in PHP

Tags: php, file, post

I would like to know why my code wont rename my file properly. Here is what I believe my code does.

- Get a `$_FILES` (file) from the POST
- Moves it to a specific folder (`uploads/`)
- Rename it to date format (I want to do this so that no file have the same name)

```
<?php

session_start();

$temps = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {

    } else {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "This is not an image -.-";
        header('location:upload.php');
    }
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "The uploaded image must be smaller than 2MB";
    header('location:upload.php');
}

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Sorry, only JPG, PNG & GIF files are allowed";
    header('location:upload.php');
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "There was an error uploading your file, please try again !";
    header('location:upload.php');
} 
else {
    $new = ($target_dir.$temps.'.'$imageFileType);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        if (rename($target_file, $new) == true)
        {
            $_SESSION['error'] = "Your image has been uploadsdsaded with success ... Hurray !";
            header('location:upload.php');
        }
        else{
        $_SESSION['error'] = "There was an error uploading your file, please try again !";
        header('location:upload.php');
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "There was an error uploading your file, please try again !";
        header('location:upload.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks you very much. I'm new to PHP so if you have any other tips please feel free to tell them :)

**Edit**: The file actually moves from the temp directory to the target directory, It just won't get renamed.

Answer (score 1):

You could just replace

```
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

with

```
$temps = time();
$target_file = $target_dir . $temps . '.' . $imageFileType;
```

And the if/else statements at the bottom with

```
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "There was an error uploading your file, please try again !";
    header('location:upload.php');
} else {
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "There was an error uploading your file, please try again !";
        header('location:upload.php');
    }
}
```

The complete file.

```
<?php
session_start();

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$temps = time();
$target_file = $target_dir . $temps . '.' . $imageFileType;

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {

    } else {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "This is not an image -.-";
        header('location:upload.php');
    }
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "The uploaded image must be smaller than 2MB";
    header('location:upload.php');
}

$allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "png", "jpeg", "gif");

if(!in_array($imageFileType, $allowed_extensions)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Sorry, only JPG, PNG & GIF files are allowed";
    header('location:upload.php');
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "There was an error uploading your file, please try again !";
    header('location:upload.php');
} else {
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "There was an error uploading your file, please try again !";
        header('location:upload.php');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my if (for the extension) seem to not be working, any reason why ?. Its suppose to be jpeg, png and gif only, yet he is letting them all in. //Nevermind, now I understand how header work, they are only applied at the end of the page. Thanks

Comment: @GabrielRoy Added the complete file with the changes to the answer, can you test it? If the file filtering still doesn't work could you add a `var_dump($imageFileType)` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

File names cannot have the ":" character. Try using something else like time() which will return the current timestamp or simply change the ":" character in your time to "-".

Comment: Only true on Windows. UNIX systems have no problem with filenames containing `:`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like below:-

```
  $arrExtension = @explode('.', $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $fileName = 'prefix-'. time() . '.' . $arrExtension[1]);
```